# Run query on previous result in Freebase

Tags: freebase, mql

I would like to run a query on a preselected set of topics in freebase.
Specifically, I'd like to find out how many, out of 1000 movies do **not** have a Netflix ID.
What I tried:

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "netflix_id": {
    "optional": "forbidden",
    "return": "count"
  },
  "limit": 1000,
  "return": "count"
}]
```

This, of course, returns `1000`. What I wanted was, to select 1000 movies

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "limit": 1000,
}]
```

and then look for objects without `netflix_id` within this result.

Can anybody help me with that?

Edit:

What I am actually looking for is a kind of statistic: *x* out of 1000 movies do not have a `netflix_id`. What I need for this is to select 1000 movies, and within this set look for movies without `netflix_id`.
For now, I simply looked for all movies without a netflix_id and divided it by the number of all movies. I posted the question nonetheless because I'd generally like to know how to use sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

The following MQL query:

```
[{
   "type": "/film/film",
   "mid": null,
   "name": null,
   "netflix_id": {
     "optional": "forbidden",
     "return": "count"
   },
   "limit": 1000
}]
```

... returns up to 1000 films that have no `netflix_id` property set. In other words, what you had was mostly correct, except for that last "return": "count", which was then aggregating the result to a single count.

**Edit**
Based on the updated explanation/requirement, you can use the following MQL query:

```
[{
   "type": "/film/film",
   "mid": null,
   "name": null,
   "netflix_id": [],
   "limit": 1000
 }]
```

... to list up to 1000 films and, if they have a netflix_id, the associated IDs. You can tell whether there are any IDs present by examining the size of the returned "netflix_id" array.

Comment: Mhhh, I think you might have misunderstood me. What I wanted to do is selet a set of 1000 movies, and then look how many of these movies have a netflix_id. What you (and I) wrote looks for 1000 movies without a netflix_id...

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the clarification. Updated. Does that solve your issue?